# Controlling the URL for a Java-web application (esp. Spring)

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

The book [Spring in Action 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294942) comes with some downloadable source code, which is organized by chapters.  The link for the downloadable software is as follows:
https://www.manning.com/downloads/1599

Here is the POM file for the Chapter 1 sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sia</groupId>
  <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>                <!--1-->

  <name>taco-cloud</name>
  <description>Taco Cloud Example</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>                    <!--2-->
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>
        UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>                                             <!--3-->
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>                                               <!--4-->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The URL to invoke the application (running on my local server) is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I would like to make changes (to the POM?) so that I can specify the chapter number with URL.  Specifically I would like to invoke the application with the following URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080/Chapter01
```

The @GetMapping annotation in the controller code uses the root path (i.e. "/"), which I want to retain.

Kindly suggest pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the controller to have a common base address or URL path, what you can do is add `@RequestMapping("/Chapter01")` annotation to your controller.

Your controller will look something like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Chapter01")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/")
    // some get method        

}
```

Now you use the following URL to call this method: `http://localhost:8080/Chapter01/`

Comment: The suggested fix works but what is the significance of the trailing "/" i.e. why is it that `http://localhost:8080/Chapter01/` works but `http://localhost:8080/Chapter01` does not?

Comment: Your @GetMapping("/"` annotation governs this. If you remove '/' from your annotation and use this @GetMapping(""), you can use http://localhost:8080/Chapter01to make the call. But this won't be recommended.